# Raman amplification

Tags: visible-light, raman-spectroscopy

Recently I read a bit about [Raman amplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raman_amplification). Unfortunately, I did not understand everything. As far as I understood the resulting wavelength only depends on the pumping wavelength. Now I heard on the one hand that the light which should be enhanced must have the same wavelength as the scattered light. I understand that physically, because the wavelength of the signal light matches the energy of the elevated molecules. But on the other hand I also read that I can enhance light whose wavelength differs from the other wavelengths. I did not understand that. How is that light able to bring the molecules down? I mean, the energy differs, and therefore there should not be an interaction. Is that right? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: The resulting wavelength depends on the pump wavelength and the energy of the vibrational state transition that is taking up the excess energy.  Different media will have different Raman shifts.  I have used H2 gas cells to shift 1064 nm (Nd:YAG) to 1.8 microns - the H2 molecule has a pretty first vibration energy state. So, the light is transferring energy to the molecular vibrational states - wavelength and hence energy decrease. I'm not sure if anti-Stokes Raman amplification is even possible (photon energy increases) - you would have to get lots of molecules in the right state..

Comment: Anti-Stokes RA is possible (according to my professor) but very weak. Your explanation is nice, but unfortunately does not cover my problem (why can I use signal light whose wavelength differ from the scattered Raman light?)